# Conditionally render multiple elements inside a react fragment

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that takes a few booleans and should render an html element for each boolean if it's true. This is what I want to do:

```
function renderThis (first, second, third) {
  if (!(first || second || third)) {
    return <span>each input is false</span>
  }
  return (
  //README: This part below doesn't work. How can I conditionally render these span tags below?
    <React.Fragment>
      {
        first
          ? <span>First is true</span>
          : null
        second
          ? <span>Second is true</span>
          : null
        third
          ? <span>Third is true</span>
          : null
        credit
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

The fragment doesn't work now. I can conditionally render one element (for instance, I can render `first` if I remove the subsequent `second` and `third` variables and their associated code), but not all three. How can I conditionally render all three variables here?

Comment: You could put them in an array, but why not just enclose each in `{}`?

Comment: Anyways why would you do that? It's a highly hardcoded and inflexible code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your returned elements into an `array`. You can't return adjacent jsx

```
 <React.Fragment>
      {
        [
           true ? <span key='1'>First is true</span>: null,
           true ? <span key='2'>Second is true</span>: null,
           false ? <span key='3'>Third is true</span>: null
        ]

      }
    </React.Fragment>
```

If you are returning just the array you don't need `Fragment`

```
return [
   true ? <span>First is true</span>: null,
   true ? <span>Second is true</span>: null,
   false ? <span>Third is true</span>: null
]
```

Also, you can't return adjacent `jsx` from the same statement, but you can return adjacent unary statements

```
return(
    <>
        {true ? <span /> : null} 
        {false ? <span /> : null}
    </>
)
```

[image: Edit musing-http-zx5p9]

Comment: First way with array is great but I've never found it in React documentation

Comment: Here is the relevant [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components)

Comment: I would recommend putting the last part of your answer first, as it's a much more elegant solution. Returning an `Array` seems overly complex.

Comment: "casting downvotes", is how the community indicates which questions and answers are least useful." - https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down I truly feel like this answer is the least helpful of the solutions

Comment: What I answered I don't consider harmful, but actually the best of the solutions presented to this question. The biggest issue with your answer is it presents the array solution first, which I feel is a poor solution. While the final part of your answer is similar to some of the others, presenting it last, was well as using ternaries instead of logical operators, is why I down voted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to render all three spans based on condition of each one you could do something like this:

```
function renderThis(first, second, third) {
  if (!(first || second || third)) {
    return <span>each input is false</span>;
  }
  return (
    //README: This part below doesn't work. How can I conditionally render these span tags below?
    <React.Fragment>
      {first && <span>First is true</span>}
      {second && <span>Second is true</span>}
      {third && <span>Third is true</span>}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think credit is a variable. Other than that I totally agree this a better approach!

Answer (score 0):

The `Array` approach seems overly complicated to me. Why not just this?

```
<React.Fragment>
   {true  && <span>First is true</span>}
   {true  && <span>Second is true</span>}
   {false && <span>Third is true</span>}
</React.Fragment>
```